# When developing CloudFoundry apps using Eclipse, what project types are allowed?

Tags: eclipse, cloud-foundry

May I ask for some clarification on what sorts of projects can be successfully deployed to vcap_dev please?  What I'd like to deploy is a dynamic web project that includes java and javascript, but that appears to not be allowed.  Is it possible to include javascript/html/css artifacts in a deployed app?  If so, what project type should I use?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [vmc command line tool](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/vmc-quick-ref.html) to see what runtimes and frameworks are supported in your vcap_dev setup. The commands are slightly different depending on the version of `vmc` you install:

- use `vmc runtimes` or `vmc info --runtimes` to see what runtimes are supported
- use `vmc frameworks` or `vmc info --frameworks`  to see what frameworks are supported

This question was also posted to the [vcap Google group](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/d/topic/vcap-dev/uRqV36XGTfc/discussion), see that thread for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spring framework by installing the Cloud Foundry Integration Extension for SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) and Eclipse (http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/STS/configuring-STS.html). Then you can add javascript / css / html files as resources.

Let me know if that answers your question.

Thanks,

Hitesh